# Exclude a part from a URL (Webpage)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to share a URL excluding a part from the top of the webpage. On the top of my URL (I do not have permissions to change it) I have a div that I don't want to share. I want to exclude this content before sharing the link.

*In order to achieve that, I found a way to create an embedded link where I can exclude some parts of the page using the "margin" method and setting it to negative.*

*For example in the HTML I have this code :*

```
<div class="yolo " style="border: 3px solid #c90001; overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 736px;"><iframe src="http://apolosiskos.co.uk" width="300" height="150"></iframe></div>
```

*and then this part in the CSS :*

```
iframe
{
margin-top:-20px;
}
```

*This works* but I wonder whether there is a way to directly share a URL and at the same time exclude a part of it. So, instead of having to create an iframe on my website and share this, I am hoping there is a way to share any link and include something in the URL in order to exclude a part of it.

The idea is something similar to the image URLs in some websites. For example this one :
[ONE](https://media.formule1.nl/2016/09/F1_2016_Germany_18-180x180.png)

can be shown as :

[TWO](https://media.formule1.nl/2016/09/F1_2016_Germany_18-1500x600.png)

A) Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to achieve by just changing/altering the URL?

B) Is there any other way of sharing a webpage by excluding or including specific content instead of having to create an iframe in a new page?

```css
iframe
{
margin-top:-50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="yolo " style="border: 3px solid #c90001; overflow: hidden; margin: 15px auto; max-width: 736px;"><iframe src="http://apolosiskos.co.uk" width="300" height="150"></iframe></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without access to edit the page, you are limited in what you can do.

Below are some technical solutions but i would try talking to the page owner about doing this. Hacky solutions like those in 2 or 3 are prone to breaking as your code will potentially break if the third part site changes.

1. If you had access to edit the page (or could influence the development of it), you could enter a query string value (parameter in the url) and render the page differently according to this value.
2. If you are on the same domain, or the page owner is willing to allow cross origin access, you could use javascript on your 'proxy' page to request the entire external page using ajax, then strip out certain parts and present the stripped down data to your users.
3. Another option is to create a page to proxy the content (just like in option 2) but do this on the server side using something like php, asp etc. This will allow you to request the third party site content via a server side request (and strip it accordingly). As this is not being done by javascript, you won't run into cross origin issues.